# Setting CSS attributes on Change using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change css `visibility` and `display` attributes using jQuery on `click` when the state of another `div`'s `visibility` attribute changes. (Many apologies for the obfuscated markup, but needing to manipulate someone else's construction):

There are four instances of `[data-label="Checkbox"] [data-label="Checked"]` in this page. I want to set `[data-label="trash"]` **and** `[data-label="Sort Options"]` to `visibility: visible; display: [empty value]` when **any** of the `[data-label="Checkbox"] [data-label="Checked"]`'s attributes changes to `'visibility', 'visible'`.

Else, if **none** of `[data-label="Checkbox"] [data-label="Checked"]`'s have the attribute `'visibility', 'visible'`, I want to set `[data-label="trash"]` and `[data-label="Sort Options"]` back to their initial states: `display: none; visibility: hidden;`.

Here's the markup:

```
<div data-label="Sort Options" style="display: none; visibility: hidden;">
    <div data-label="trash" style="display: none; visibility: hidden;"></div>
</div>

<div data-label="Checkbox">
    <div data-label="Unchecked"></div>
    <div data-label="Checked" style="display: none; visibility: hidden;"></div>
</div>
```

Here is what I have tried unsuccessfully:

```
$('[data-label="Checkbox"]').click(function() {
    if ('[data-label="Checkbox"] [data-label="Checked"]').css('visibility', 'visible') {
        $('[data-label="trash"], [data-label="Sort Options"]').css({'display': '', 'visibility': 'visible'});
    } else {
        $('[data-label="trash"], [data-label="Sort Options"]').css({'display': 'none', 'visibility': 'hidden'});    
    } 
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 if ('[data-label="Checkbox"] [data-label="Checked"]').css('visibility', 'visible')
```

first of all `.css()` is used to set or get css , the way you are using here is setter , the get should be like

```
if ($('div[data-label="Checkbox"]').css('visibility')=='visible'&& $('div[data-label="Checked"]').css('visibility')=='visible')
```

Second you can use a selector for two elements without logical operator , as you can see i have used `&&` to check that both `'visibility'` are set to `'visible'`

if you set `display` to none , you dont have to use `visibility` attribute , eventhough the standard to use is `display`.